# POST Queries in Swift for given website

Tags: ios, database, swift, http, post

I am trying to make queries to get the fuel type and consumption of a specified car (the user enters both make and model) for an iOS app written in Swift.

The app is targeted for Spain, and I have found a website that allows the user to enter make and model, and it returns the details for that car (http://coches.idae.es/portal/BaseDatos/MarcaModelo.aspx). I have seen using the tool WireShark, that the query is based on POST instead of GET. But I am not quite sure how I can make the requests within the app I am developing, or how to handle the info that is sent to me back from the sender.

Is there any way to make those requests to the given website? If so, I would really appreciate some help on the subject, I am new in iOS development and am looking forward to learning as much as possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show some codes please?

Comment: Which version of swift are you using? You can use [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to send request. [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is nice tool if you want to see what come in/out.

Answer (score 0):

Many people prefer to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) for making HTTP requests. However you don't need to do that. You said that its a POST request. Setting that up is easy even without AFNetworking using `NSMutableURLRequest`. I'm assuming you have a link to the API and not just to the aspx page. My Spanish is pretty weak so I can't look up the API reference for you but here's how you can make the request and receive data from the server. You will have to put the correct values and parse the responses:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "/* Paste URL here */")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
// Do this as many times are required for filling in the headers.
request.addValue("/* The value for the HTTP header */", forHTTPHeaderField: "/*The header field like Accept-Type, etc..*/") 

// If you need an HTTP body too then make the JSONObj as a dictionary or array or whatever and then
let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObj, options: [])
request.HTTPBody = data // This needs to be NSData. 

// Now make the request.
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
        assert(data != nil)
        let JSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [NSObject: AnyObject] 
        // If you are using swift 2 this needs to be in a do try catch statement.
        // TODO: Use JSON for whatever.
    }
    else
    {
         print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task?.resume()
```

Let me know if you have any other questions or if the API doesn't use JSON or is completely different.